# How does oneget handle updates?

Tags: windows, powershell

I've been looking at oneget, the new windows package manager (mamager) and I cant seem to find any info on how it updates your downloaded packages.

The program doesnt seem to have a Update-Packages command (or something akin to choco update all)

Does anybody know if its possible or do we have to update packages manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [an issue](https://github.com/OneGet/oneget/issues/58#issuecomment-58545244) posted in the OneGet repository:

> Update-Package will be coming soon

However, that statement was posted on Oct 9, 2014, so "soon" doesn't seem likely.

EDIT: Seems like [this issue](https://github.com/OneGet/oneget/issues/6) is still being discussed (as of November 2015)

Comment: Thanks I'll follow that discussion